# Why is my React checkbox onChange handler firing on render and then not when the box is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have read through the React docs and boiled the problem down to a simple case, still can't quite understand what I'm doing wrong.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/justin_levinson/pyn7fLq5/ or written below:

```
var TestForm = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Test Form</p>
                <form>
                    <TestBox />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var TestBox = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (<input type="checkbox" name={"testbox"} defaultChecked={true} onChange={this.handleCheck()}/>)
    },
    handleCheck : function(event) {
        console.log("check");
        console.log(event);
    }
});
```

When the page loads, I get a 'check' in the log followed by 'undefined' for the event, then it doesn't fire again on subsequent clicks.  Have tried this with both onClick and onChange as well as creating a controlled (checked={true}) instead of the uncontrolled (defaultChecked={true}) above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you're already calling the method on render.

change `onChange={this.handleCheck()}` to `onChange={this.handleCheck}`

Comment: What if you need to send a parameter?

Comment: @RMontes13 `this.handleCheck.bind(null, parameter)`

Answer (score 10):

For anyone reading this in the future (like me), you can also solve this by formatting like `onClick={(e) => this.handleCheck(parameter)}` if you need to pass in a parameter.